# Drupal7 modified user login no effect?

Tags: php, templates, drupal, authentication

I am new to Drupal. I am trying to create a modified login page.

I have modified the template.php of my theme with the name "cmse" in /sites/all/themes/cmse/

This is my template.php:

```
<?php
function cmse_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'homepage';
  $vars['classes_array'][] = 'teaser';
}
function cmse_theme() {
  $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'cmse') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'user-login',
  'preprocess functions' => array(
  'cmse_preprocess_user_login'
  ),
 );
return $items;
}
```

This is the new file "user_login.tpl.php" in /sites/all/themes/cmse/templates

```
<?php
    // split the username and password so we can put the form links were we want (they are in the "user-login-links" div bellow)
    print drupal_render($form['name']);
    print drupal_render($form['pass']);
    ?>
    <div class="user-login-links">
    <span class="password-link"><a href="/user/password">Forget your password?</a></span> | <span class="register-link"><a href="/user/register">Create an account</a></span>
    </div>


    <?php
        // render login button
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['actions']);
    ?>
```

All changes doesn't have any effect to my login page. Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of reasons.

Drupal cache is very notorious so ensure to clear cache. You can do that via instructions [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache)

> Clearing the cache The easiest way to clear the Drupal cache is to go
>   to Administration > Configuration > Development > Performance
>   (http://example.com/admin/config/development/performance) Click the
>   button "Clear all caches"

Have you selected your new theme instead of existing one?
Follow Instructions [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal/drupal_themes.htm) on how to select a new theme.

Further just replacing values to the new theme name cmse may not work. The right way to do this would be to add a custom module and then call the .tpl.php file from there.